# How correctly make sequence for WSO2 API? It's breaking email send

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I create simple api with URI-template 
/my_context/{param1}?b={param2}

I created simple sequence for sending email message to endpoint with address

```
mailto:user@gmail.com
```

I opened link

```
/api/my_context/123?b=222
```

And found in log messages:

```
Send TO: user@gmail.com/my_context/123?b=222
Incorrect Address.
```

Why WSO2 ESB append uri to email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `REST_URL_POSTFIX` property like this will change that behavior.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"  action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can read about this "details". In wso2 docs I found only simple examples, which dosn't help me solv this problem.

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-Property:REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX